# ¿Porque me muestra None en consola tras el input (el código no tiene funciones)?

Tags: python-3.x

En el código se pide una entrada por consola y cuando se ejecuta el input() aparece tras el input() None. Este es el código:

```
comprobar = True
while comprobar:
n1 = int(input(print('Inserta el primer número: ')))
n2 = int(input(print('Inserta el segundo número: ')))   

ver = False

if n1 > 0 and n2 > 0 and n1 != n2:
    comprobar = False
    if (n1 < n2): 
        aux = n1
        n1 = n2
        n2 = aux

    i = n1
    while not ver and i >= 1 : 

        if n1 % i == 0 and n2 % i == 0:
            print('El mcd es',i) 
            ver = True 

        else:
            i -= 1 

else:
    if n1 == n2:
        print('Los números son iguales.')

    else:
        print('Los números no son válidos.')
```

None suele aparecer cuando usas print() por return en una función pero aquí no definí ninguna función, por lo que no sé que es lo que causa None, porque en el input() especifico que es un int el tipo de entrada.

Answer (score 0):

Es porque dentro de la función `input` se ha anidado la función `print` trata de reemplazar lo siguiente

```
n1 = int(input(print('Inserta el primer número: ')))
n2 = int(input(print('Inserta el segundo número: ')))
```

por

```
n1 = int(input('Inserta el primer número: '))
n2 = int(input('Inserta el segundo número: '))
```

Y desaparecerá el `None` de la consola cuando se ejecute el código.